# Styled-Component / Emotion.js Is object-style or template style prefered over another?

Tags: styled-components, emotion

I like cleanesss of object-style

```
const Button = styled.button(
  {
    color: 'darkorchid'
  },
  props => ({
    fontSize: props.fontSize
  })
)
```

however template(?) style seems to be the main interface that supports more features than object style

```
const Button = styled.button`
  color: hotpink;
`
```

Is css-string (template) style prefered (or more featured or supported) over object-style in StyledComponent or Emotion.js ?

- Edit

For one difference I know I don't think it's possible to do this with object style

```
const dynamicStyle = props =>
  css`
    color: ${props.color};
  `

const Container = styled.div`
  ${dynamicStyle};
`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tagged template literals are used much more than objects because the latter was introduced in [v3.4](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v340---2018-08-02). By this time Styled component was already very prominent.

More than the looks there are no known difference. I personally prefer template literals because that gives the touch and feel of having actual CSS if you use IDE plugins such as [vscode-styled-components](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jpoissonnier.vscode-styled-components)

**Edited**

here is the code for your edited question:

```
const dynamicProps = props => css`
  background: ${props.color};
  font-size: ${props.fontSize};
`;

const SquareOne = styled.div(
  {
    width: "100px",
    height: "100px",
    background: "blue" // will be overwritten by dynamicProps
  },
  dynamicProps
);
```

[Sandboxed](https://codesandbox.io/s/template-literal-dkqwh)

Comment: `More than the looks there are no known difference` I edied the op.. please take a look

Comment: Here is a discussion from the styled components devs why they chose string templates over objects: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3078